# Xcode, Touch Detect on the Screen, not the UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uitouch

i had done a code for detect the touch events, it works when i want to detect the location. The problem is, When i go in "Begin Touch" events, "Location X" is 110. after that i move around the Image from Middle to Bottom, than move to Top and finally i put back on Middle. the "Current Location X"(Get from "Touch Moving" Events) is completely not match the "Location X"

sample image 1 >
Log return, at the start, location.x = 110; currentlocation.x = 110;

sample image 2 >
after i start move the image.
location.x = 110; currrentlocation.x = 130~150(move to bottom side,number will keep increase when i holding the image on Top);

*sample image 3 >
after that i move the image to top.
location.x = 110; currentlocation.x = 120~140(move to top side,number will keep decrease when i holding the image on Bottom);

means now i never can make the "location.x" = "currentlocation.x" after i move the image.

i assume because the frame i using is UIScrollView, so it was detect the Scrollview location, not the screen view location. so is that any can tell me how to solve the bugs? or where i wrongs?

```
    - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (touches.count == 1)
    {
        UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
        location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
        self.touchCount = 0;
        [self addSubview:s_overlayContainer];
        [self.delegate cardChangeBackGround:self];
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (touches.count == 1)
    {
        UITouch *touchcheck = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
        currentLocation = [touchcheck locationInView:touchcheck.view];
        int LzcurrentTopBottom = LzTopBottom;
        self.touchCount++;
        // location > current = next
        // location < current = previos
        if(self.touchCount > 2)
        {
            if(currentLocation.x < location.x)
            {
                LzTopBottom = 1;
            }
            else{
                LzTopBottom = 2;
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"Current >>> %f,%f",location.x,currentLocation.x);
        NSLog(@"Current >>> %d,%d",LzTopBottom,LzcurrentTopBottom);
}
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: you need to use the gesture to detect ....

Comment: @Spynet, you means i cant use "TouchesBegan", "TouchesMoved" and "TouchEnd"?

Comment: Yes you cann't use those methods...